# What is the semantics of decorations for python classes?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have the following code

```
class B:
  registry = {}

  @classmethod
  def Register(cls, name):
    def InnerWrapper(wrapped_class):
      if name in cls.registry:
        print('\'{}\' has been registered!'.format(name))
      print('Hey, this is a wrapper for {}!'.format(name))
      cls.registry[name] = wrapped_class
      return wrapped_class
    return InnerWrapper

@B.Register('A')
class A:
  def __init__(self, arg):
    self.arg = arg

  def __call__(self):
    print(self.arg)

a1 = A('xxx')
print('instantiated a1')
a1()
a2 = A('yyy')
print('instantiated a2')
a2()

print('== Define another class that wrongly registers \'A\' again ==')

@B.Register('A')
class C:
  def __init__(self, arg):
    print(arg)
```

My question is this: The two instantiations of class A will not cause the warning of "'A' has been registered". Rather it is only at the definition of class C which also has a decoration of B.Register('A') that will cause the warning to be printed.

So what is the semantics of decoration for classes in this case? It seems to me that the decoration is executed only once per class definition. Why is this the case? And where is the documentation for this design?

Comment: The decoration is run when the code it decorates is run (when you import the module, run it as a script, etc). There is [nothing special](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3129/#semantics) about the semantics of class decorators.

Comment: `@B.Register('A')` `class A: ...` is exactly equivalent to `class A: ...` `A = B.Register('A')(A)`. It works exactly like it does with functions. (e.g. try decorating a function, the decorator isn’t called on every call of the function). Also, remember that the decorator is the function returned by `B.Register('A')`.

Comment: Decoration is only applied once per definition of decorated class or function. For functions/methods this is documented at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/ and applies to classes in the same way.

Comment: Thank you guys, I got it. So it is at "compile time", the B.register('A') is called, which returns the InnerWrapper, which receives the python class as argument, and returns the "new class" definition as class. Since we return exactly wrapped_class, which is A itself, the class definition is not changed, but we registered it in B.